How to make Qt-creator use Global Menu and not use KDE breeze theme under Plasma
I have Qt-creator on my system (Manjaro with KDE plasma 6) installed through different way:
If it is installed via qt-maintenance-tool in $HOME:

It does not export Menu Bar so no Global Menu (it works under X11 but not under wayland).
It does not have the KDE version of the file dialog.
It does not have Breeze theme applied.
It is perfectly fine otherwise.

If it is installed via pacman in /bin:

It exports Menu Bar
It does have Breeze theme applied.
It does have KDE file dialog.
Weird glitches or artifacts occur: context menu sometime show up normally, sometime in their own window or does not show at all. The terminal tab is completely messed up: it changes color when a mouse or keyboard button is pressed.

I want to achieve a set up where:

Menu bar are exported correctly under wayland.
Breeze theme is not applied (can be solved with command line argument: --style fusion.
it uses KDE file dialog.
no artifacts with context menu.

.
